# Cross-loaded indicators in factor analysis (before regression analysis)

Tags: regression, factor-analysis

I performed exploratory factor analysis, and extracted two underlying factors out of eight indicators. Then, I used confirmatory factor analysis for some theoretical fine-tuning. After minor revisions, the model yielded significant results, as far as CFI, TLI, RMSEA and SRMR are concerned.

But I ended up with two indicators that are cross-loaded on two factors as follows:

```
F1 F2
i1
i2
i3
i4 i4
i5 i5
   i6
   i7
   i8
```

Under the circumstances, is it a problem to compute a mean score out of the indicators under each construct for use as predictors in a regression analysis? That is, if I average `i1-i5`, and `i4-i8`, to use as predictors in a subsequent regression analysis.  More precisely, how much of a problem, if at all, is it that indicators `i4` and `i5` are represented in both predictors `F1` and `F2`?

Comment: Are all of the weights identical? If not, I don't see how the end result is equivalent.

Comment: No, they are not, so I think I now see your point. Does the weighting also answer my question? Should I not worry about cross-loading, once the weights are taken into consideration?

Comment: That's a good question, & a subtle issue. I'll let someone w/ more expertise provide an official answer. I *think* you're OK if you use the factor scores, despite the cross loading.